# List nodes from Firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

I try to read data from Firebase but it doesn't work

**Here is what I tried :**

```
DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
await databaseRef.child('...').once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
  print(snapshot.value);

});
```

Result (OKAY) :

[image]

the structure is:

```
 id1
    key1 = val1
 id2
    key2 = val2
```

I would like to get each val (eg: val1, val2 etc)

I tried :

```
  snapshot.value.forEach((d) {
    //print(d);
  });
```

but I get :

[image]
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to loop over the child nodes of a `DataSnapshot` in Flutter. See [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20745) I created a while ago.

If order doesn't matter, you should be able to get the `Map` from the snapshot and then loop over *that*:

```
Map<dynamic,dynamic> map = snapshot.value;
map.forEach((key, value) { print('$key: $value'); });
```

---

Update: since mid 2021 the `DataSnapshot` class now has a `children` property, meaning you can *finally* do:

```
snapshot.children.forEach((child) {
  print(child.value);
});
```

Comment: it works well but when I add sthg asynchronous in the forEach (eg: await cacheManager.getFile(url), then I get "Error: Unexpected token 'await'.",  any idea?

Comment: Typically it means that you must mark the containing method as `async` though. But the code you have in your question has nothing calling async functions in there, so it's hard to be sure.

Comment: indeed I had already "async" in the method, and "await" works before I retrieve data from Firebase, any idea? I edited the code to better explain: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53821776/flutter-doing-sthg-asynchronous-while-reading-firebase-data?noredirect=1#comment94492301_53821776