# Flutter: doing sthg asynchronous while reading Firebase data

Tags: javascript, firebase, flutter

I try to do sthg asynchronous while reading data from Firebase and it doesn't work,

**Here is what I tried :**

```
Future<String> test() async {

  var cacheManager = await CacheManager.getInstance(); //await here is OKAY 

  DatabaseReference firebaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  firebaseRef.child('...').once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    Map<dynamic,dynamic> map = snapshot.value;
    map.forEach((key, url) {
       print('$key: $url');   //OKAY
       await precacheImage(new NetworkImage(url), context); //doesn't cache images
    });
  });
  return "";
 }
```

I get :

> Error: Unexpected token 'await'.

**I also tried :**

```
Future<Map> test() async {  //<---- added type Map
    ...
    map.forEach((key, url) async { //<--- added async
       //var file = await cacheManager.getFile(url);
       await precacheImage(new NetworkImage(url), context); //same, cache doesn't work
    });
```

but I get :

> E/flutter ( 3971): #1
>   __InternalLinkedHashMap&_HashVMBase&MapMixin&_LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach
>   (dart:collection/runtime/libcompact_hash.dart:370:8)

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: As said in my [answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53821089/how-do-export-data-from-firebase-database-in-realtime?noredirect=1#comment94492152_53821089), you will need to mark the method that contains this code as `async`. This is required any time you use `await`.

Comment: when I mark the method with "async" then I get "asynchronous suspension", I'm sorry but I begin and this problem is really not obvious for me

Comment: Huh? I've never had that before. Hopefully somebody else knows how to address that.

Comment: I replaced the method inside forEach with another method to try to precache images, but the preloading of images doesnt work:( urls are anyway all correct, strange...

Answer (score 2):

You pass a function to `then(...)` and in that function you use `await` and for that to work the function needs to be marked `async`.
It's not sufficient that some other outside function is marked `async`.

```
firebaseRef.child('...').once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) async { // async here was missing
    Map<dynamic,dynamic> map = snapshot.value;
    map.forEach((key, url) {
    print('$key: $url');   //OKAY
    var file = await cacheManager.getFile(url); // doesn't work
  });
```

It' might still not work but it depends on what you want to do with `file` and that's not clear from your question.

Comment: thank you but it still doesn't work, it works only if "await" is outside of map.forEach, how to do then?

Comment: Did't see it because of poor gormatting. It's the same for `map` as for `then`. Xou are passing a function.

Comment: sorry I didn't see the formatting, I edited the code to better visualize, so how to do with map, any idea?

Comment: `map.forEach((key, url) asyn {`

Comment: okay, what I tried was correct but I get another error message, I edited the question with this new issue, any idea?

Comment: the error is quite long, I added a screenshot, this bloc of error is repeated many times

Comment: The actual error message is the 2nd last mail. Xou get a Map but use type String which conflicts of coursr.

Comment: thank you but I think I don't return this map, I really don't understand this "asynchronous suspension", but thank you anyway

Comment: I think you can ignore asynchronous suspension. It only means that some other async code run at that point. Just focus on the 2nd last line in your screenshot.

Comment: oh yes sorry, I forgot to update the printscreen after changing type with Map, I updated the printscreen, so it's not errors and I can ignore all those lines? if yes, is there a way maybe to hide them?

Comment: and last question, I would like to precache images, for that I used "precacheImage(new NetworkImage(url)" but the precache doesn't work (I edited the question with this method), any idea?